# Hibernate Projection Group By Month

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate

I am Hibernate newbie and i have a working sql query which i try to re-write with Hibernate projections and restrictions. Everything is fine but when i want to group by my `time_stamp` column in `YYYY-MM` format i could not make it

How do i use `sqlGroupProjection` of Hibernate for below GROUP BY clause

> group by to_char(view_date, 'YYYY-MM')

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(YourClaassName.class);
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                        .add(Projections.groupProperty("time_stamp")));
```